# Why am I getting a compilation error in a C++ factorial function?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, conditional-operator

I am trying to write a simple factorial function in C++ by using the ternary operator. It gives a compilation error.

```
int factorial(int n) {
    (n == 0) ? return 1 : return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

It says `Expected ':' to match this '?'`
I am new to C++.

Comment: The ? operator expects expressions as arguments, not statements. This is possible with an `if`.

Comment: I doubt that returning `0` is a good idea.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah just realized it and changed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?:` is an **ternary operator** that takes three expressions and evaluates them in some way to produce a result. `return 0` in your case is not an expression but it's a statement, so your syntax doesn't work and gives error. It cannot be used where a value is expected.

The correct code and it's syntax should be as follows :

```
int factorial(int n) {
    return ((n <= 1) ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1) );
}
```

Your code would have worked in case you used if-else like this -

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if(n == 0) return 1; else return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

`if-else` is semantically different than ternary operator `?:`. You can  use statements inside `if-else`, while on the other hand, you have to use expression which evaluate to some value in case of ternary operator.

So, when you use the statement - `return ((n <= 1) ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1) );`, the **ternary operator will get evaluated first** and it will give out a value (*which is why the expression inside **ternary operator** need to evaluate to a value*)according to the satisfied condition and that value is eventually returned by the `return`.

Hope you understand the difference and this solves your doubt !

Comment: Also _fact_ should be _factorial_ for recursion to work.

Answer (score 2):

Possible fixes:

```
if (n <= 1) return 1; else return n * f(n - 1);
```

or

```
return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1);
```

---

Note that it is a common exercise to implement the factorial as a recursive function. Anyway, due to the fast growth of the function, an `int` can only accommodate up to `12!`, and storing the precomputed values is probably a better idea.

Comment: Also _fact_ should be _factorial_ for recursion to work and add the explanation from the comments to the answer too.